# Actionbar launch fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, fragment

How can I launch a fragment from onOptionsItemsSelected?

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case R.id.action_support:

              Fragment f = new SupportFragment();
                          FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(android.R.id.content, f).commit();



              Toast display = Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", 10);
              display.show();
          case R.id.action_guide:
              Toast display1 = Toast.makeText(this, "Guide", 10);
              display1.show();
             return true;
          default:
             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
    }

}
```

Im trying to launch the support fragment.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4vnzxmypv6hggvh/error.txt

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 13:06:37.231: W/System.err(27967):  at openday.SupportFragment.onCreate(SupportFragment.java:18)

Look at line 18 in SupportFragment.java class there is a nullPointerException, or edit your post and post the whole code to get the problem solved, but this seems another problem

Comment: thanks, found the issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   Fragment fragment; 
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_support:
                fragment = new Home();
            case 1:
                fragment = new NotesList();
            default:
                fragment = new defaultPageOrAnyOtheOption();
    }

  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
  return true;

} // onOptionsItemSelected
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code, I have updated my original post with the code and also a link to the logcat output as it still crashes the app

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case R.id.action_support:

              //launch Support Fragment
             // Fragment f = new SupportFragment();
             // replace(android.R.id.content, f);

              Toast display = Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", 10);
              display.show();
          return true;
          case R.id.action_guide:
              Toast display1 = Toast.makeText(this, "Guide", 10);
              display1.show();
             return true;
                     }
    }
```